# Android gradle error (libGDX)

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I was using libGDX 1.3.1 for months now. Everything was good as nothing involved gradle but now I want to use gdx-facebook 1.1.1 libGDX extension. The gradle build fails if I want use the gdx-facebook extension (1.3.1 and 1.9.x as well). It has something to do with the gdx-facebook extention.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.android.support:support-v4:[22,23) as no versions of com.android.support:support-v4 are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
         https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
         https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/support-v4/
         https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
         https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/support/support-v4/
 Required by:
         911:android:1.0 > de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-android:1.1.1 > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0
```

I even downloaded the support repository using the SDK manager.

Comment: Please show Your build.gradle files so we do not need to guess. Mostly sure You're trying to use version of support-v4 that is not available in jcenter or maven central repository that You are using.

Comment: Thank you for your time tommus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Sometimes android SDK manager doesn't show all the packages,  why I really don't know. Earlier I thought support repository under the extras was the cause, I did download it but the error was still present but  today SDK manager showed local maven support repository, I downloaded it and everything is cool now.